# Streaming bytes to remote in a multipart HTTP request .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await

I'm trying to create a .net core http client that would stream bytes to the remote server in a `multipart/form-data` request. The bytes to be sent are generated dynamically by another task. At the moment of sending of the request I don't have the full data to be send in memory or anywhere - this data will be produced during the course of the request by another task. I tried to use the `MemoryStream` as a source for the `StreamContent` and feed this memory stream from another task but it's not suited for such case. Is there any stream in the standard library that could be use?

It would be best if I could access the request's stream and write (push) directly to it but I'm not sure how to do that in the case of multipart request.

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        using var contentData = new MultipartFormDataContent();

        Stream sharedStream = SomeKindOfStream(); // <-- Need a stream that another task could write to and close
        var streamContent = new StreamContent(sharedStream);

        contentData.Add(streamContent, "file", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

        using (var httpResponseMessage =
            await httpClient.PostAsync("http://localhost:5000/async/abcd",
                contentData))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Got Response: '{await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()}'");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use HTTP Request wen you can use TCP with a NetworkStream?  The contents of the TCP connection can be html and you can parse the HTML on the server after all the data is received.

Comment: A multipart HTTP request is just an HTTP Request. HttpClient just provides helper methods. You can use Fiddler or Wireshark to look at the request content and see what's on the request and replicate it, if that's what you want.